# Unable to retrieve Users (Not logged in) through WP Rest API

Tags: users, api

We are able to retrieve Rest API results of our WP database, running a Learndash plugin.

We can retrieve details while not logged into the WP site, although limited (10 records or so).

While logged in though or not logged in, if we try the application password, it produces a 404 error and we cannot obtain any other records. The site has close to 900 users.

We can obtain other records nicely with the application password, while not logged in, using other endpoints.

Any ideas?

Comment: It quite common for security plugins (if you've got one?) to block the users endpoint, though it's very odd it only does that logged in.

Comment: If you disable Learndash temporarily does the user list work again? Ditto other likely plugins?

Comment: Otherwise I think you'll have to debug this yourself: are the requests actually getting to WP_REST_Users_Controller, or what's filtering them out along the way.

Comment: Thank you for responding. We tried the deactivation of all plugins. Doing that made no difference, so we're a bit stuck. You're right though that a security plugin can and will play a part in this hurdle we have.